# Problema en CSS con <li> , background

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema al generar mi[css](/questions/tagged/css), y no tengo idea, o por lo menos, no doy en el clavo. Quisiera que mi `<li class="selected">` tenga el background color "rojo" pero no se puede.

Dejo mi código:

```html
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>Prueba de navbar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="desktop_menu" id="desktop_menu">
     <div id="sidebar">
      <ul class="categories">
       <li><a href="#" class="selected">inicio</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">envíos locales</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#">solicitar envios (nac - int)</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">contacto</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">pagos</a></li>
       <li class="selected"><a href="#">clientes e-commerce</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html> 



    <style>
    .categories {
     list-style:none;
     color:#666;
     background:#f7f7f7;
    }
     .categories li {
      font-size:14px;
      color:#666;
      background:#f7f7f7;
      height:39px;
      border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9;
     }
     .categories li:first-child {border-top:none;}
     .categories li a {
      display:block;
      height:39px;
      line-height:39px;
      padding:0 8px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#666;
      background:#f7f7f7;
     }
     .categories li a:hover, .categories li a.selected {
      font-weight:bold;
     }
     .selected li {
      background: red; 
     }
    </style>
```

Comment: `selected li` debería ser `li.selected`, indicando _"cuando un elemento `li` tenga la clase selected..."_.

Comment: en realidad debería ser `a.selected`

Comment: He intentado con sus respuestas, pero ninguna tiene una solución en sí.

Comment: Yo cambié en el html

<li class="selected"><a href="#" >inicio</a></li>

y en styles puse

.categories .selected a{
            background: red;
        }

Comment: Gracias @KevinZerull ! Esa era la respuesta. Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 2):

`<a>` es un bloque y está por encima de `<li>` por lo tanto no se muestra el fondo del `li` ya que lo cubre `a`

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Prueba de navbar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="desktop_menu" id="desktop_menu">
     <div id="sidebar">
      <ul class="categories">
       <li><a href="#" class="selected">inicio</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">envíos locales</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#">solicitar envios (nac - int)</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">contacto</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">pagos</a></li>
       <li class="selected"><a href="#">clientes e-commerce</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html> 



    <style>
    .categories {
     list-style:none;
     color:#666;
     background:#f7f7f7;
    }
     .categories li {
      font-size:14px;
      color:#666;
      background:#f7f7f7;
      height:39px;
      border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9;
     }
     .categories li:first-child {border-top:none;}
     .categories li a {
      display:block;
      height:39px;
      line-height:39px;
      padding:0 8px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#666;
      background:#f7f7f7;
     }
     .categories li a:hover, .categories li a.selected {
      font-weight:bold;
     }
        /*AGREGADO*/
     li.selected {
      background: red; 
     }
      li.selected a {
      background: none; 
        color: white;
     }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Prueba de navbar</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="desktop_menu" id="desktop_menu">
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="categories">
        <li><a href="#" class="selected">inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">envíos locales</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">solicitar envios (nac - int)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">pagos</a></li>
        <li class="selected"><a href="#">clientes e-commerce</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html> 



<style>
.categories {
list-style:none;
color:#666;
background:#f7f7f7;
}
.categories li {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#666;
    background:#f7f7f7;
    height:39px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
.categories li:first-child {border-top:none;}
.categories li a {
    display:block;
    height:39px;
    line-height:39px;
    padding:0 8px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;
    background:#f7f7f7;
}
.categories li a:hover, .categories li a.selected {
    font-weight:bold;

}
.categories li a.selected{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Esta bien lo que hiciste, pero solo quiero que la clase "selected" o ID "selected", SOLO ESA PARTE, este en rojo, sin necesidad de hacer un hover, que tenga un background en color rojo.

Comment: pruebalo ahora porque no entiendo bien lo que quieres lograr

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con el selector a pelo

```
#sidebar > ul > li > .selected{
   background: #FF0000;
}
```

Pero aquí veo algo raro...

```
<li><a href="#" class="selected">inicio</a></li>
   ...
<li class="selected"><a href="#">clientes e-commerce</a></li>
```

Le estás metiendo la clase selected a un `<a>` y más abajo a un `<li>`